# Parallel Brute-Force Algorithm

Tags: c#-4.0, brute-force, parallel-extensions

So I was looking at http://codahale.com/how-to-safely-store-a-password/# and became curious how fast  different hash could be bruteforced on a somewhat powerful desktop computer and was tempted to test it

Most of the algorithms I've seen though are single-threaded and it struck me that this would be a really interesting  challenge in using c# 4.0 Parallel.net/Plinq extensions and concurrent structures (like ConcurrentBag and IProducerConsumer).

So my task is as follows, build the most efficient/performant bruteforce checker of a password of n-length and charset[x] using parallelization, ie generate all possible strings of a given charset and length until a match is found. Assume at least two cores and reasonable amount of ram

I'm going to give it a whirl myself, let the best man/woman win :)

**EDIT**

First attempt without comparing performance yet and limited scope and known password length

```
    char[] chars = new char[] { '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z' };

    public long NrCombinations(int nrChars, int stringLength)
    {
        Func<long, int, long> power = null;
        power = (i, p) => p == 1 ? i : i * power(i, p - 1);

        return power(nrChars, stringLength);
    }


    public static bool StringArrayEquals(char[] a, char[] b)
    {
        if (a.Length != b.Length)
            return false;
        for (int i = 0; i < a.Length; i++)
        {
            if (!a[i].Equals(b[i]))
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public char[]  GenerateString(int i, int stringLength)
    {
        char[] current = new char[stringLength];
        for (int i = 0; i < stringLength; i++)
        {
            double remainder = i % this.chars.Length;   
            i = i / this.chars.Length;         
            current[i] = this.chars[(int) remainder];
        }
        return current;
    }

    public bool IsMatch(int i, char[] password)
    {
        return StringArrayEquals(GenerateString(i, password.Length), password);
    }

    private int GetMatching(string passwordString)
    {
        char[] password = passwordString.ToArray();
        int nrCombinations = (int)NrCombinations(this.chars.Length, password.Length);

        return ParallelEnumerable.Range(0, nrCombinations).WithDegreeOfParallelism(10).FirstOrDefault(i => IsMatch(i, password));

    }
```

**Next Attempt**

Using ParallelEnumerable wasnt to clever since it's restricted to int in size, you pretty soon need atleast long even though I doubt that will hold you for long with large passwords charsets. Guess you either have to go BigInt or start breaking it down somehow after that.

```
    public long NrCombinations(int nrChars, int stringLength)
    {
        Func<long, int, long> power = null;
        power = (i, p) => p == 1 ? i : i * power(i, p - 1);

        return power(nrChars, stringLength);
    }


    public string GenerateString(long number, int sentenceLength)
    {
        char[] current = new char[sentenceLength];
        for (int i = 0; i < sentenceLength; i++)
        {
            double remainder = number % this.chars.Length;   
            number = number / this.chars.Length;         
            current[i] = this.chars[(int) remainder];
        }
        return new string(current);
    }

    public bool IsMatch(string hash, long  i, int passwordLength)
    {
        string generated = GenerateString(i, passwordLength);
        string hashed = GetMasterHash(generated, this.site);
        return string.Equals(hashed, hash);
    }

    private string GetMatching(string hash,int passwordLength)
    {
        string result = string.Empty;
        int stringlength = passwordLength;
        long  nrCombinations = NrCombinations(this.chars.Length, stringlength);
        long x = 0;

        Parallel.For(0, nrCombinations, (i, loopState) =>
        {
            if (IsMatch(hash,i, passwordLength))
            {
                x = i;
                loopState.Stop();
                return;
            }
        }); 


        if (x > 0)
        {
            result = this.GenerateString(x, passwordLength);
        }

        return result;

    }
```

Comment: just generating the string combinations.. running them through  a hash can always be added on top later

Comment: can you put a documentation for the code ? :)

Answer (score 0):

Why the `NrCombinations` method and not just

```
long combinations = (long)Math.Pow(base, stringLength);
```

I would also recommend against `int` for `nrCombinations` because with only six characters with your base 36 alphabet you will get in trouble (36^6 > 2^31). Use `long`. I don't think `BigInteger` is needed because if you need that big numbers brute force will not be an option anyway.

I have this idea that it might be possible to speed up brute force by using a kind of De Bruijn sequence stream. Seems reasonable but I have to get back on that because I have no code to show right now.

Comment: Math.Pow uses double so it wouldnt scale for larger numbers

Comment: True but 2^53 is a lot to brute force.

Comment: you can never have too much brute force ;)