# Generate All possible combinations using Membership.GeneratePassword in C#

Tags: c#, random

I have tried looking for the solution. But i was unable to find any. I am trying to produce all possible combinations using the Membership.GeneratePassword(int length, int numberofnonalphanumericcharacters) function.

Now, i want that for the length of the password, it creates all possible combinations. Thanks.

Comment: probably you look for the Brute-Force Algorithm implementation, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4463379/parallel-brute-force-algorithm might help. Membership.GeneratePassword just generate one string password not all possible combinations, it`s like Guid.NewGuid() nothing more that that.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Though i would still prefer some easier way rather than getting into brute force  :( .